# Symfony 2.8 dependecy injection issue

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I have small issue with dependency injection service in Symfony2 and I cant figure out whats wrong.I have followed example from http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html. Maybe someone fresh look can sort this out and code(btw i dont want to extend controller or pass this as a argument to the class constructor):

```
services:

    app.custom_mailer:
        class:     NTPBundle\Mailer\CustomMailer
        arguments: ['@mailer']
```

CustomMailer.php

```
namespace NTPBundle\Mailer;
class CustomMailer {

private $mailer;
public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}


public function weekExtractMail() {

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('no-reply@test.com')
            ->setTo('no-reply@test.com')
            ->setBody("Test"
    );
    $this->mailer->send($message);
    return $this;
}
```

}

and PDFTestController.php

```
namespace NTPBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class PDFTestController extends Controller{
    /**
     * @Route("/pdftest")
     */
    public function pdfTestAction() {
        $mailer=new \NTPBundle\Mailer\CustomMailer;
        $mailer->weekExtractMail();
        return new response($this->renderView('NTPBundle:PDFReports:weekVolumes.html.twig', array()));
    }
}
```

and error

**Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to NTPBundle\Mailer\CustomMailer::__construct() must be an instance of NTPBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface, none given, called in C:\wamp64\www\src\NTPBundle\Controller\PDFTestController.php on line 19 and defined**

I have looked in debug container and service is defined.

Comment: *I have looked in debug container and service is defined.* - then use it instead of instantiating your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem looks to be your defining a service, but then instantiating the service using new. To allow for symfony to do its things (and actually inject the dependencies) you need symfony to instantiate the service using the [service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) most likely:

```
$mailer = $container->get('app.custom_mailer');
```

*Edit: In a controller you can just use `$this->get` as symfony made an easy alias for it.*

Comment: Purpose of this excise was to use dependency injection which should live outside controller therefore there is no access to container but actually you may be right and instead of creating new object     `$mailer=new \NTPBundle\Mailer\CustomMailer;` i should call `CustomMailer::weekExtractMail();` i will test that this afternoon and confirm

Comment: Well you don't need the controller, you need the service container for symfony to do the dependency injection. I just said the controller has a shortcut to get the container class as its a common place where you would use services.

Comment: This answer is completely right, no need to test anything different. It even says at the very top of your linked symfony docs that it's related to the service container. Also: *"actually you may be right and instead of creating new object [...] i should call CustomMailer::weekExtractMail(); i will test that this afternoon and confirm"* - How would calling that method as a static suddenly make `$this->mailer` available (heck, you don't even have `$this` in a static call...)? Are you always guessing? Long story short: You **need** the service container to get an instance of your CustomMailer.